# Dependency Injection of Value Types

Tags: c#, azure, dependency-injection, microservices, azure-service-fabric

I am creating an Azure Service Fabric service and relying on the native .NET framework for dependency injection through constructors. The problem is: one of the constructors has as parameter a value type (specifically System.TimeSpan). How should/can I register such type with the dependency injection framework?

To clarify: I am trying to follow the examples shown here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection#service-lifetimes-and-registration-options

Comment: Do you really want to register such global type? I always use a specific class for this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If possible, consider adding an interface like `IDurationProvider`, that has a property of type `TimeSpan` and register a type that implements it instead. This clarifies the developer & usage intent.

If you decide you really need this, this will work:

```
 services.AddTransient(typeof(TimeSpan), _=> TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1D));
 var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
 var timespan = (TimeSpan)serviceProvider.GetRequiredService(typeof(TimeSpan));
```